# Replacing an ebike's cable disc brakes with hydraulic disc

Tags: brakes, safety, electric-bike, cable, pads

I have a Viking Gravity 250w 24v ebike.

I'm just wondering if I can replace the braking system with a hydraulic type and what would happen to the wired braking safety feature? Would I have to retrace the connection and remove it?

Any information would be appreciated as the brakes are rubbish and constantly need adjusting etc.

Also why are my brake pads red? Are they a certain type e.g. ceramic etc?

[image]

Comment: A lot of hydraulic brakes don't like being hung upside down, folder that flips the reservoir on the handlebars upside down might be problematic.

Comment: Where do the sensor wires for the Brake cutout go to. The lever or the calliper?.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I'm curious: what sort of safety feature are you and the OP talking about? Is it a motor cutout switch?

Comment: @WeiwenNg Yes, it should tell the controller to drop motor power when braking. The photo doesn’t show any wires to the calliper so probably goes to a switch in the lever at best guess.

Comment: There to the levers

Comment: Tektro HD-E710 have a sensor for E-Bike use. Other brands may have something.  People have bodged up sensors on standard levers with things like magnetic switches, but given it is a safety feature, its probably best not to.

Comment: What about replacing the cr....y brakes with cable pulled self contained hydraulic units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have eliminated contamination of pads or rotor as the cause you can consider a different calliper.

The bike spec on the website lists the brake spec as “Mechanical disc with alloy 3 finger levers.”

A drop in replacement might be an Avid BB7 or BB5 or Shimano BR-M375 calliper which might improve the strength of the brake without needing to figure out the mechanics of the cut-out switch at the lever.

However, mechanical disc callipers can also depend on good pull ratios at the lever to work well so you might need to figure out how to reproduce the switching mechanism with a new lever if a new calliper doesn’t give you everything you want.

The carrier metal of the pads is red because it looks cool. They are probably organic type pads for when it’s time to replace.

Comment: Thank you Warren for your help..also Warren I'm quite new on ere how /were is the check marker?